# Eigenvector for a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have $T:\mathbb{R³} \rightarrow \mathbb{R³}$ an Endomorphis associated with the matrix
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
       -14 & 43 & -22 \\ 
       1 & 20 & -14 \\
       3 & 25 & -21
    \end{matrix} \right)$$
I would like to calculate the Eigenvalues and the Eigenvector.
I calculate easily the Eigenvalues $λ_{1}=7$, $λ_{2}=-11$, $λ_{3}=-11$, so we can see that $λ_{2}=λ_{3}=-11$, so $-11$ has mulptiplicity two. I found also the first Eigenvector $v₁=\left(1,1,1\right)$, I did the same thing with $v_2=\left(-10,8,17\right)$, but we know that $-11$ has multiplicity two, so we have to find a third Eigenvector, but I don't know how to calculate this.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Cf. [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector)

Comment: I did this computation with mathematica, I think there is only this two Eigenvectors, but my question is why there are only this two and not three?

Comment: [algebraic multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity) greater than geometric multiplicity

Comment: $-11$ may have mult. 2. But this implies that $dim(N(A+11I)) \leq 2$. Equality does not hold always. I mean third eigenvector may not exist.

Comment: But I have to proof something else to say this?